# Main menu disappeared in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, user-interface, menu, visualization

I've got a problem with Visual Studio 2013 Professional Edition since this morning. I cannot see the main menu (see screenshot). The only extension installed are "Productivity Power Tools".

I already tried:

- devenv /ResetUserData
- devenv /ResetSettings

But the main menu keep disappeared...

Any ideas?

[image: VS2013 without main menu]

Comment: When I use devenv /safemode everything is fine!

Comment: I also tried the repair function using VS2013 setup.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Changed the UI language using **devenv /LCID** from german to english and backwards and everything works fine! Thx!